# @Aftermapping to set field in protobuf message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mapstruct

```
@Aftermapping 
default void setObjectVals (@MappingTarget Target taregtProto, Source source) {
    taregtProto.setABC(source.abc); 
}
```

There is no way to set protobuf field like this. it can only be added through builder. How can we set field in @Aftermapping ?

Answer (score 0):

When using builders like in the case of Protobuf you can use the builder in an `@AfterMapping` method

e.g.

```
@AfterMapping
default void setObjectVals(@MappingTarget Target.Builder targetBuilder, Source source) {
    // Do what needs to be done
}
```

Comment: yeah... I figured it out after a while. looks like it was not included in the reference guide though, is it?

Comment: You mean the last paragraph of https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after?
 "when using a builder, the `@AfterMapping` annotated method must have the builder as `@MappingTarget` annotated parameter so that the method is able to modify the object going to be build."